# Deep Speech install

Tags: software-installation, tag

i have just downloaded and installed Ubuntu on a new PC. I have now downloaded Deep Speech by Mozilla.

I cannot find an installation file, as in windows systems, so how do I install and activate this software?

Comment: Did you read this: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/master/README.md it covers mostly everything, it seems but I have no experiance with it, so can't really help further than, install pip and use that to install it `sudo pip install deepspeech`

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is the [prototype](http://blog.mikeasoft.com/2017/12/30/speech-recognition-mozillas-deepspeech-gstreamer-and-ibus/) by Michael Sheldon that makes DeepSpeech available as an IBus input method. Just add [the](https://launchpad.net/~michael-sheldon/+archive/ubuntu/deepspeech) [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~michael-sheldon/+archive/ubuntu/gst-deepspeech), install `ibus-deepspeech`, and restart the X server. You should then be able to add "English (DeepSpeech)" as an input source.

Note that this is basically alpha software; it is definitely not ready for prime time. But it's a pretty good start.